# Symfony Semantical Error as constraints

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

After typing this command (`php app/console generate:doctrine:entities CoreBundle:Post`
) by Terminal the error below appears, How can I solve this?

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>   [Semantical Error] The annotation
>   "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints" in property
>   Blog\CoreBundle\Entity\Post::$body does not exist, or could not be
>   auto-loaded.

Source Code:

```
namespace Blog\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post extends Timestamp
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
 *
 * @Assert|NotBlank
 */
private $body;


/**
 * @var Author
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referecedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected  $author;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return Post
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set body
 *
 * @param string $body
 * @return Post
 */
public function setBody($body)
{
    $this->body = $body;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get body
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getBody()
{
    return $this->body;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a typo in the `@Assert` annotation on the `$body` property. You're using a pipe symbol `|` instead of a backslash `\`.

Comment: Thank's your answer @lxg

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If so, please *accept* the answer. Thanks!